# How we solve iterated integrals such as this one?

Tags: calculus, iterated-integrals

Here is the problem

> $(\textbf{20}\text{ points})$ Calculate the following iterated
> intergals:
>
> $$\text{a. } \int_0^2\mathrm dx
>  \int_{-1}^1\big(3x^2-(x+y)e^y+xy^3\big)\ \mathrm dy,$$

I can do the next if you explain how to solve this.
Thanks!

Comment: You do the $y$ integral considering $x$ a constant.  When you evaluate it at the limits $y$ will disappear because it is a dummy variable.  You then have a single $x$ integral..  The $xy^3$ term integrates to $\frac 14xy^4$.  Plugging in the limits gives $\frac 12x$

Answer (score 0):

I personally dislike this notation, and think it's easier to see it written as:
$$
\int_0^2\int_{-1}^1(3x^2-xe^y-ye^y+xy^3)\mathop{dy}\mathop{dx}
$$

Evaluate the $y$ integral first, considering $x$ as a constant:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1(3x^2-xe^y-ye^y+xy^3) \mathop{dy}&=\left.\left[3x^2y-xe^y-(y-1)e^y+xy^4/4\right]\right|_{y=-1}^{y=1}\\
&=6x^2-\left(e-\frac1e\right)x-\frac2e
\end{align*}

Then evaluate the outer integral:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^2\left(6x^2-\left(e-\frac1e\right)x-\frac2e\right) \mathop{dx}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand better. Thanks!!